# Uploading shapefile to GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, shapefile, layers, php

I successfully created workspace in GeoServer using cURL in PHP following the GeoServer REST Guide. But I am having problems when trying to upload Shapefile. I followed the instructions on Uploading Shapefiles from GeoServer REST Guide but I can't seem to get it right. I keep getting Wrong Magic Number error. Also I want to upload shp file rather than zip.

I am a beginner in GIS.

**Update**

Everything works fine when I use CURL

```
curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XPUT -H "Content-type: application/zip" --data-binary @trash.zip localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/mySpace/datastores/‌​…
```

but fails with the following PHP code:

```
<?php $ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:9090/geoserver/rest/workspaces/mySpace/dat‌astores/trash/file.s‌​hp"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$post = array( "file" => "@" .realpath("trash.zip") ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "admin" . ":" . "geoserver"); 
$headers = array(); 
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/zip"; 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
$result = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close ($ch); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

A shapefile (despite it's name) consists of between 3 and 9 files sharing a common prefix but with different suffixes. You need to zip up all of the files to get a successful upload.

Comment: Thank you for the response.
I did zip the files and did this...
curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XPUT -H "Content-type: application/zip"
  --data-binary @trash.zip
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/mySpace/datastores/trash/file.shp

This runs perfectly when done in Command line tool but does not work when is converted to php.

Comment: then you need to add the php code you are using

Comment: Oh. Sorry!
`<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:9090/geoserver/rest/workspaces/mySpace/datastores/trash/file.shp");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$post = array(
    "file" => "@" .realpath("trash.zip")
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "admin" . ":" . "geoserver");
$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/zip";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
?>`

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to upload the shapefile to GeoServer. I followed [**this article**](http://cnokello.blogspot.com/2012/09/geoserver-rest-api-with-php.html) by Okello Nelson. Very well explained and working article.

Thank you!

Comment: I found the answer for my question in an article which i have linked in the answer. The article has explained everything in detail. That is the reason I linked the article.